# Problemas al instalar composer require maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, excel

Buenas tardes necesito exportar a excel desde laravel con php, tengo la version 8.
Cuando quiero instalar `composer require maatwebsite/excel` me da el siguiente error:

> Problem 1
> - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.27, ..., 3.2.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, 1.17.0, 1.17.1].
> - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, 1.16.0, 1.17.0,
> - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
> - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.17.1] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
> - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.2.x-dev].

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
> You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿O que otro componente podría utilizar? Gracias.

Comment: Mira en esta parte del mensaje "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.17.1] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.", te dice que falta una extensión de php. Luego en "To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files: - C:\xampp\php\php.ini" te dice cómo hacer para habilitar una extensión que ya esté instalada, típicamente es quitar el `;` (punto y coma) que tiene delante.

Comment: Buenisimo era eso., mil gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

se soluciona incluyendo extension=gd en el archivo php.ini en la direccion xampp/php

Comment: TE AMO user222949, funcionó. coloquenlo sin los ; al inicio que tiene todo el archivo solo copien y peguen en cualquier linea en blanco del documento y funciona extension=gd